# How to allow Caching API endpoint that requires Authorization header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I was looking at a way for caching responses from an API endpoint developed in .NET Core. The request to the API must have a valid `Authorization` header as part the requirement.

I came across a few articles mentioning that caching wouldn't be possible if the request contains `Authorization` header, which was a bit of surprise to me.

[image: Response caching conditions]

So how should I tackle this problem? Are there any libraries that can possibly enable caching for this kind of scenario?

Comment: It shouldn't be too much of a surprise :) Different users might be able to get different data, and caching those requests by default would create potential data leaks. There might be a setting for controlling that behaviour.

Comment: FYI: "Warning: Disable caching for content that contains information for authenticated clients. Caching should only be enabled for content that doesn't change based on a user's identity or whether a user is signed in." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response#responsecache-attribute

Comment: @juunas - Thanks. It makes sense. But the tricky bit here in my case is that the Auth header must be required, even though the response data isn't user specific, e.g. static custom type and category enums, etc.

Comment: @crgolden - thanks. pls see my comments above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `The Authorization header must not be present.`, this is by default.

For `ResponseCachingMiddleware` which will call `IResponseCachingPolicyProvider` to check whether to cache the reponse by `if (_policyProvider.AllowCacheStorage(context))` like below:

```
// Should we store the response to this request?
if (_policyProvider.AllowCacheStorage(context))
{
    // Hook up to listen to the response stream
    ShimResponseStream(context);

    try
    {
        await _next(httpContext);

        // If there was no response body, check the response headers now. We can cache things like redirects.
        await StartResponseAsync(context);

        // Finalize the cache entry
        await FinalizeCacheBodyAsync(context);
    }
    finally
    {
        UnshimResponseStream(context);
    }

    return;
}
```

And, [ResponseCachingPolicyProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/cc1f23c5f8afb7d2a00405f19811d2372c4fcec2/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching/src/ResponseCachingPolicyProvider.cs#L25) will check `HeaderNames.Authorization` by

```
public virtual bool AttemptResponseCaching(ResponseCachingContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

    // Verify the method
    if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(request.Method) && !HttpMethods.IsHead(request.Method))
    {
        context.Logger.RequestMethodNotCacheable(request.Method);
        return false;
    }

    // Verify existence of authorization headers
    if (!StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization]))
    {
        context.Logger.RequestWithAuthorizationNotCacheable();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

For [ResponseCachingPolicyProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/cc1f23c5f8afb7d2a00405f19811d2372c4fcec2/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching/src/ResponseCachingPolicyProvider.cs#L25), it is internal which you could not change from outside `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching`.  It is not recommended to enable cache for `Authorization`, if you insist on, you could implement your own `ResponseCachingMiddleware` by refer [ResponseCaching](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/cc1f23c5f8afb7d2a00405f19811d2372c4fcec2/src/Middleware/ResponseCaching).

Comment: Can you please help us to implement that middleware?